# Installing rsyslog from source - No package 'liblogging-stdlog' found

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, rsyslog

I asked this over in AskUbuntu but have had no luck with an answer. I am doing experiments with different logging systems. At the moment I am trying to install rsyslog from source so I can make some modifications to it. I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I downloaded version rsyslog 8.4.0 from their website. When making, the following error comes up:

> no package 'liblogging-stdlog' found

I can't find this software in apt-get which makes it difficult to know how to pursue this further. What do I need to install here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you're looking for is here:

- http://packages.ubuntu.com/cs/utopic/liblogging-stdlog-dev

You can download the DEB file specific to your architecture (32-bit/64-bit). If you don't want to install the package like this you could disable the need for this library based on this thread:

*excerpt - http://lists.adiscon.net/pipermail/rsyslog/2013-December/035091.html*

> > It sounds like a library that Rainer may have made as part of his
> >     refactoring of the rsyslog code base for v8, but since there isn't a lot
> >     of documentation for v8 yet (since Rainer is concentrating on making it
> >     work before documenting how to make it work), some guesswork is required
> >     to build the v8 source
>
> removed --enable-rfc3195 to get rid of liblogging problem (after
>   some  googling it seems liblogging is needed for RFC 3195 support), it
>   seems  that I don't need it,
>
> erik

Or you could download it from source and build it yourself.

*excerpt - same thread above*

> > ```
> > $ git clone git://git.adiscon.com/git/liblogging.git
> > $ cd liblogging
> > $ autoreconf -fvi
> > $ ./configure --help
> > $ ./configure
> > $ make
> > $ make install (or checkinstall)
> > ```

Comment: i look forward to marking this as correct once i can get it installed. the deb file is not installing as it says there is an error and for some reason ubuntu's autoconf is unable to process the autoreconf command above.

Comment: thanks, this worked after i installed the liblogging-stdlog0 library deb package before trying to install this...

Comment: btw, the configure command to disable those options is:  ./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-liblogging-stdlog --disable-rfc3195